# php CURL occasionally slow namelookup_time

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

I use to CURL to fetch json strings from 2 API's services. each time I have around 20 querys to run for both API's. 
i do it with -
`exec()` 
this mean I open 40 threads, in each one of them, a single curl is preformed:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, true );
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

most of the time this run is done pretty fast (1 second for all the threads), but once in 5-6 runs, in few (1-3) of those 40 threads, I come across `namelookup_time` of about 5 seconds where usually it takes around 0.005 second !

another confusing matter - this exact process runs on two other servers, and it doesn't happens there (e.g. - all the CURL namelookup_time are very fast). the problematic server is a production server but not at all crowded (this process doesn't run all the time, just on demands - about 20 time an hour)

I've know about curl_multi but it's expensive for me to change the code to this format, and more than that - I am not sure it will solve this problem.

Some clue that might help - in the logs, It look like a consistent delay, when ever it happens it take 5 seconds more than usual, so perhaps there is some waiting definition somewhere?

Any direction anyone?

Comment: curl can only ever be as fast as the network conditions allow.  If, for example, the DNS server is slow to respond then the full curl request will take at least as long as the DNS lookup takes to complete.  Your best bet is finding ways of minimising the impact of the curl script, for example by caching its results or launching a process to do it in the background for you.

Comment: But why does the DNS server act like this? on most cases it resolves very fast and in few it waits for 5 sec. on other machines this problem does not occur. How can I check the DNS server performance?

Comment: eventually I've added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);` and rerun this call if it was timed out.